# React-Native button wrapping, a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity

I'm trying to wrap a button that already exists with the functionality of `recordActivityTag`. Right now the way it is working it is not capturing the function of the data from the first button. I need to follow tags throughout the app. That's why I've constructed `recordActivityTag`. That functionality works fine for events, except for buttons.

How do I call within the `onPress` - if that's possible - the action on a button from another screen? I know I need to pass in the outer prop into TouchableOpacity and then call the other button.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Core } from "common";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

interface BtnProps {
  readonly data: string
  readonly recordActivityTag:(tag: Core.ActivityTag) => void
}

export default class Button extends React.Component<BtnProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: BtnProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { recordActivityTag } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        onPress {() => recordActivityTag}
        {this.props.children}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you give your function to the `onPress` prop of the `TouchableOpacity` component, and that you actually call `recordActivityTag` within it.

```
export default class Button extends React.Component<BtnProps, {}> {
  render() {
    const { recordActivityTag } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => recordActivityTag()}>
        {this.props.children}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Put the render within the 'export'?

Comment: @Buzz I have not changed the render method from your question, except this line: `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => recordActivityTag()}>`.

Comment: How would I, just basic, set this up to be called within a page or card? I'm setting a tag to a button on another page.

Comment: I'm sorry @Buzz, I don't quite understand what you are asking. I might have misinterpreted the question, but I thought the question was how to call the `recordActivityTag` function when the `TouchableOpacity` is pressed.

Comment: That is the question.This needs to wrap around another button so that when the other button is pressed this will track that action. Maybe I'm thinking of this wrong.